# Android PieChart with SQLite database value

Tags: android, sqlite

Im new in android and currently im making a piechart that has a value from my database and my codes here has no any error appear but its not working. i dont know where is the error.. Thanks in advance. i hope hope anyone could help me with this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graph_budget);

    pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.pie_budget);

    setDataChart();
}

public void setDataChart(){

    DBHelper db = new DBHelper (getApplicationContext());
    List<Budget_PieChartList> names = db.getListPieChart();

    pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);
    pieChart.animateXY(1000, 1000);
    pieChart.setHoleRadius(36f);
    pieChart.setDescription(null);

    ArrayList<PieEntry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());


    float total_amount = db.getTotalAmount();

    for(int index = 0; index<names.size(); index++){

        float amount = (names.get(index).getAmount()/total_amount)*100f;
        yVals.add(new PieEntry(amount, index));
        xVals.add(names.get(index).getName());
    }

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals, "");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);
    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    PieData dataPie = new PieData(dataSet);
    dataPie.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    dataPie.setValueTextSize(12f);
    dataPie.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
    legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);

    pieChart.setData(dataPie);
    pieChart.highlightValues(null);
    pieChart.invalidate();
}
```